# CD40106 output voltage

Tags: digital-logic, input, cmos, output

I'm testing some CD40106BE from Texas Instrument, CMOS Hex Schmitt Trigger ([Datasheet Here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd40106b-mil.pdf)).

Vdd = 5V (Pin14)
Vss = GND  (Pin7)
Vin = 5V

I measured a Vout = 3.8V on every IC I tested, with a Led on each output, is that normal?
Watching Fig.9 I should have Vout=5V, isn't it?

Comment: What color LED and what value of current-limiting resistor?  The bog-standard red LED drops 1.7V and needs about 10 mA to drive to reasonable brightness for indoor use.  That's a LOT more current than a CD40106 can drive.

Comment: Yes, it is normal with an LED on each output. Drawing any current from the output will bring Vout below the supply voltage, and you are drawing a relatively large current for this device.

Comment: @JoeHass OK, so can I put a multimeter intead of the led? So I should measure the correct tension, isn't it?

Comment: @JoeHass Done, with the only multimeter on the output it shows the correct voltage. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not normal:

[image]

If you have less than 0.5 mA load on the output, it should be able to reach 4.6 V. If you have a very small load, it should reach 4.95 V.

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem? The circuit is very simple, only a led and a resistor on every output, 5V and GND from Arduino Uno. I've tested 9 pieces, same results on each one.

Comment: If you have an LED on the outputs you are drawing a lot more than 0.5mA! That is extremely important information you should have put in your original question. The chips are working just fine.

Comment: @TheEscapist, What color LED and what resistance? Most LED drive circuits allow for at least 3-5 mA  and 10 or 20 mA are not uncommon for ordinary indicator LEDs. These original CMOS logic chips were only designed to drive other CMOS logic chips which require practically no input current. They are not designed to provide enough current to light an LED

Comment: @TheEscapist: A huge weakness of the CD4k series is its cripplingly low output current. That's why I prefer to use 74HC whenever possible.

Comment: @ThePhoton yes, the leds are only for testing its funcionality, the CD40106 will be connected to a ULN2003. I've put also a pull-down resistor on each input.